# Minimax is not returning the optimal move

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe minimax function. I'm not sure what the logic error is in my code. Would someone mind helping?

Note that `best` is at max, a 4 digit number that contains (row, column, score, score) from left to right. So 1110 would mean at the square (1,1) which is the middle of the 3x3 board, the score is 10.

```
int checkEndGame() {// return -1 win, 1 win, 0 draw, 12345 if nothing else.
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if ((board[i][0] == board[i][1]) && (board[i][1] == board[i][2]) && (board[i][0] != 0)) { // check rows
      return board[i][0];
    }
    if ((board[0][i] == board[1][i]) && (board[1][i] == board[2][i]) && (board[0][i] != 0)) { // check columns
      return board[0][i];
    }
  }
  // Check diagonals
  if (board[1][1] != 0) {
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[2][2])) { // left to right
      return board[0][0];
    }
    if ((board[2][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[0][2])) { // right to left
      return board[2][0];
    }
  }
  // Check empty squares
  for (int row=0;row<3;row++) {
    for (int column=0;column<3;column++) {
      if (board[row][column] == 0) {
        return 12345;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // otherwise it's a draw. // Done
}

int minimax(int plyr) {
  int best;
  if (plyr == 1) { // Maximize
    best = -99;   // Worst score
  } else {           // Minimize
    best = 99;    // Best score
  }

  int endGameValue = checkEndGame();
  int score;
  if (endGameValue != 12345) {
    score = endGameValue * 10;
    return score; // This never runs after
  }

 for (int row=0;row<3;row++) { //rows
    for (int column=0;column<3;column++) { //columns
      if (board[row][column] == 0) {
        board[row][column] = plyr; // Sets the available slot as the current plyr.
        score = minimax(-plyr); // row, col, score, score
        board[row][column] = 0; //reset the board so we don't mess it up
        int scoreVal = score % 100; // this works.
        if (plyr == 1) {
          if (scoreVal > best) {
            best = scoreVal;
            if (best >=0) {
              best += row*1000;
              best += column*100;
            } else {
              best -= row*1000;
              best -= column*100;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (scoreVal < best) {
            best = scoreVal;
            if (best >=0) {
              best += row*1000;
              best += column*100;
            } else {
              best -= row*1000;
              best -= column*100;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return best;
}
```

Comment: This scheme that you have with folding the position into the score, won't that break down at the next level up where the score returned from the recursive call already has a col/pos value in it, but then, if it's the new best, you add them again?